# Problem with two cards nested in a radio group

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I embedded a radio button in two cards. To group them together I nested the two cards inside a btn-group.
This works very well but the layout crashes on small display sizes.
When it shrinks down to xs the two columns should fill one whole row but it doesn't happen. The second card vanishes you can't scroll to it.
I tried a lot but I can't make it work on small screens.
When I omit the radio group wrapper the layout works but obviously my radio buttons don't.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <!-- Grid row -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="mb-4">Card Title 1</h5>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="card-circle d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                      <i class="fa fa-users light-blue-text"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <p class="grey-text">Paragraph 1.</p>
                  <label id="label1" class="btn btn-secondary active" for="input1">
                                                                    Radio1
                                                                    <input type="radio" id="input1"
                                                                           name="name1"
                                                                           value="val1" checked>
                                                                </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-lg-0 mb-4">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="mb-4">Card title 2</h5>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="card-circle d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                      <i class="fa fa-user light-blue-text"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <p class="grey-text">Card paragraph 2.</p>
                  <label id="label2" class="btn btn-secondary" for="radio2">
                                                                    <input type="radio" id="radio2"
                                                                           name="name1"
                                                                           value="val2">
                                                                    Radio 2</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Not working but not layout breaking:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <!-- Grid row -->
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="mb-4">Card Title 1</h5>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <div class="card-circle d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-users light-blue-text"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p class="grey-text">Paragraph 1.</p>
                <label id="label1" class="btn btn-secondary active" for="newSurgery">
                                                                    Radio1
                                                                    <input type="radio" id="input1"
                                                                           name="name2"
                                                                           value="val1" checked>
                                                                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-lg-0 mb-4">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="mb-4">Card title 2</h5>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <div class="card-circle d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-user light-blue-text"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p class="grey-text">Card paragraph 2.</p>
                <label id="label2" class="btn btn-secondary" for="radio2">
                                                                    <input type="radio" id="radio2"
                                                                           name="name2"
                                                                           value="val2">
                                                                    Radio 2</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Can you explain more in details?

Comment: I want to spread two radio buttons over different divs. To accomplish this I wrapped the two divs in a radio-group. While this works well it breaks my layout on small screens.

Comment: @DavidLiang I added a second piece of code without the radio group wrapper. This is how it should look like. Unfortunately this way the radio buttons don't work.

Comment: I don't understand. By "radio-group", you meant the "btn-group" class? Anyway, the radio buttons have nothing to do with their surrounding HTML elements. In order for them to work, you just need to have the same name in each radio button.

Comment: Sorry I meant btn-group. That's what I thought but please try the first example. It works once. But when you click radio2 and after that radio1 radio1 won't be selected. Example 2 works that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your second snippet works fine, you just got the `for` attribute wrong on the 1st label, so you need to click the actual radio button to see it working.

If you change the `for` attribute, from the non existent `newSurgery` to `input1`, it will work as expected:

```
<label id="label1" class="btn btn-secondary active" for="input1"> 
<!-- not for="newSurgery"-->
    Radio1
    <input type="radio" id="input1" name="name2" value="val1" checked>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think radio buttons have anything to do with their surrounding HTML elements. You just need to have the same name for them:

```
<input type="radio" id="input1" name="HAVE_TO_BE_THE_SAME" value="val1" checked />
<input type="radio" id="input2" name="HAVE_TO_BE_THE_SAME" value="val2" />
```

The `name` is what groups the radio buttons together. You can have different `id` and `value`. The label `for` attribute points to the `id` of the element, not the name.

And you have too many unnecessary row and column markups. Try to read the bootstrap documentation one more time.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!--
            By default, the div is displayed as block so you don't need
            `col-12` unless they're not displayed as block and you force them
            to.
         -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card"> ... </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card"> ... </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/250477/